# Authorization failed due to insufficient permission

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am trying to implement multiseller onboarding in paypal with a sandbox business account.
I am getting authorization error when trying to make authorization request on Paypal sandbox environment.
Error message: "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions"
I am getting successful response for access token generation.

{
"name": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
"message": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
"debug_id": "b38caf2692623",
"information_link": "",
"details": [
{
"issue": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"description": "You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."
}
],
"links": []
}

I just used the payapal developer documentation for multiseller onboarding and used Postman.
I could create the access token successfully, but when using the access-token for partner referral link i am unable to get the response